# R Reference classes and hierarchial data

Tags: r, oop

I am trying to understand the reference classes in R based on hierarchical data. I have got the data below

```
Name  Visit  Value 
Peter   0      54
Peter   1      50
Andi    0      48
Andi    1      47
```

Now I want to build a OOP system out of it with my base class "Visit" (with the fields Visit and value), then the class "Subject" (with the fields Name and inheriting from Visit) and the final class "Frame" (inheriting from Subject and only a field subject). I am using the code below and I am wondering whether this is the correct implementation:

```
visit <- setRefClass("Visit",           
                  fields = list(visit="numeric",
                                value= "numeric")
                  )

name <- setRefClass("Name",
          contains="Visit",
                  fields = list(name = "character", 
                            vis= "list")
                  ) 

frame <- setRefClass("frame", contains="Name", fields = list(subject = "list"))

frame$new(subject = list(c(name = "Peter", vis = list(c(visit=0, value=54), c(visit=1, value=50))),
          c(name = "Andi", vis = list(c(visit=0, value=48), c(visit=1, value=47)))))
```

Is this a good implementation?

Cheers,
Andi